# Use INDEX to lookup multiple values in a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using this formula to Look up all instances of CUCUMBERS in column B on the first sheet of my workbook: "ITS" I have identical to column B in Column X.

So far this works great, just as I want it, except it ONLY returns some of the CUCUMBERS, not all of them. I am using the same formula swapped around to find the PO# which is found in column D, so I can tell which CUCUMBERS it is sending back to me, and it is skipping the first two in this search.

Keep in mind, my data includes other produce like SPINACH, KIWI, CARROTS, etc... all of which is located both above and below the CUCUMBER entries, which is why the CUCUMBERS are on rows 24:30. This formula needs to be able to pull data from the whole column, and return EACH instance of the name; so if there are 15 entries for CUCUMBER, I need it to reflect 15 entries on my second sheet.

The basic goal here is to find each instance of a specific item of produce, and pull all of the data from each row where that item is listed. If there is any easier way to do this, I am open to that as well. Here is the info below:

> =INDEX(ITS!$B$4:$X$56,SMALL(IF(ITS!$B$4:B56=$B$1,ROW(ITS!$B$4:B56)),ROW(ITS!3:56))-3,23)

Here is an example of the ITS sheet:

```
       B               C          D

 24   CUCUMBER  ANDREW&WILLIAM  381873

 25   CUCUMBER  ANDREW&WILLIAM  381873

 26   CUCUMBER  ANDREW&WILLIAM  381873

 27   CUCUMBER  DIVINE          611881

 28   CUCUMBER  WHOLESUM        100328

 29   CUCUMBER  WHOLESUM        100328

 30   CUCUMBER  DIVINE          1002874
```

The issue is that when I run the formula; I only get back the bottom 5 to return, and it skips over the first two entries.

Answer (score 1):

You start your formula in row 3 that's why it starts from 3rd result. Either start in first row or use `ROW(ITS!3:56)-2`.

Why do you need to use formula at all? I'd use pivot table (if you need to show cucumber in each row you can set "repeat item labels").

Answer (score 0):

The `ROW(ITS!3:56)` argument of `SMALL` doesn't make sense.

**What your formula is doing now:**

The `SMALL` function is calling for the `{3,4,5,...,56}`th smallest item in your array of matches *in a single cell*. By pure accident, this has the illusion of working as intended because only the first term in this array is used in the single-cell formula. So, in your first entry, you get the 3rd smallest item.

When you fill down, it calls for the `{4,5,6,...,57}`th item, and by coincidence, the 4th smallest item. And so on.

**What you want the formula to do:**

You want the last argument of `SMALL` to be a single number (not an array) that is incremented by 1 as the formula is filled down.

You can achieve this by using `ROWS` instead. In the first formula, use this as the last argument in `SMALL`:

```
`ROWS($1:1)`
```

This will increment by 1 as you fill down the formula.